# Can kafka client version 0.10 work with kafka server version 2.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

We have Kafka cluster that uses Kafka 2.1.1 and we are using Flink built-in Kafka connector(client）that is using 0.10.

I would ask whether Kafka client version 0.10 can work with Kafka server version 2.1.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a client running 0.10 can connect to a cluster running a newer release including 2.1.

The client obviously won't be able to use the newer features. The Kafka broker will also have to convert the messages from and to this old client which can have a performance impact. Apart from that, it should just work.

Comment: Reference: point 5 under "For a rolling upgrade" on https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation.html#upgrade

Comment: Thanks @MagnusReftel and Magnus for the answer!